# Library to receive detailed health data streamed from wearable

Tags: android, ios, health

We can read sample data from Garmin Connect, Polar Accesslink, and Google Fit via their corresponding APIs. This is very convenient, as the user does not have to use anything but the device they already have, and just authorizes the app to read the data.

This, however, is only sample or aggregated data, and I would like to have more information, and looking for a library to receive detailed health-related information from a wearable.

Specifically: RR interval, heart rate broadcast, HR with sample time of < 10 seconds, oximetry.

From what I understand, this library will have to use a bluetooth-based SDK ([Polar BLE](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk) and [Garmin Companion SDK](https://developer.garmin.com/health-sdk/overview/) respectively) to connect to the device and stream data and save data as it is made available.

Is there a library that I can use on Android or iOS (preferably both) to connect and read out data from a Garmin or Polar device and then do the normalization? Also, support for other devices would not be bad.

Related follow-up question: Is there any such API available for the Apple Watch? So far, I have only found  the [HealthKit Statistics Query](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsquery)